# swift array/dictionary advice

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

so basically i am going to be saving a few sets of data, each set contains 6 string information, so the array will have to look like this

```
[set1 ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"][
set2 ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]...
etc.... ]
```

i could have have quite a few sets, id like all this to be in one object and i would also like to access the strings within, with the "set1"/"set2" keyword.

the problem is am fairly new to swift i don't know if this is an array or dictionary or even something else, any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a standard swift Dictionary to achieve what your looking for.

```
var info = Dictionary<String, [String]>()
info["set1"] = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]
info["set2"] = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]
```

Accessing by key would be as simple as the following:

```
if let setInfo = info["set1"] {
    // do what ever you want
}
```

In Swift 2 you could do the guard and exit early if you wanted

```
guard let setInfo = info["set1"] else { return }
```

Removed the casting per comment it is not required for this since the definition of the Dictionary implies they will be [String]

Comment: casting from [String] to  [String]? You only need to unwrap the optional value

Comment: Altered and put the note in per your suggestion (was a little too type happy there)

Answer (score 1):

This is an array:

```
let arr:[String] = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]
```

This is a dictionary:

```
let dict: [String: String] = ["key 1" : "value 1", "key 2" : "value 2"]
```

It seems to me that you need a dictionary (since you want to have access to your arrays of strings using "set1"/"set2" keys), which has `String`s as keys and arrays of `String`s as values:

```
let requiredDictionary: [String: [String]] = [
"set1" : ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"],
"set2" : ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]
//...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a dictionary where the values are arrays of strings.

```
var info = [String:[String]] // Key: String, Value: [String]
info["set1"] = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]
info["set2"] = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]
```

This is now a dictionary.

You access the arrays with a key:

```
print(info["set1"]![2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary with the "set1", "set2", ... keys and an array of the 6 strings as the object linked to these keys.

Thus you would access the 3th string of the second set with:
  data["set2"][2]

That sounds pretty usual to me.

Anyway you can organise the objects/strings the way you want, there is no specific flavour. The only important thing is that you feel ok and at ease with it.

Answer (score 1):

Tips on choosing a collection type:

If you want the items to be ordered, use an array.

If you want to be able to retrieve an associated value using a key, use a dictionary.

If you just need a "bag" of values that are not ordered, but are unique, then use a set.